# Chrome extensions add home button and show bookmark bar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to add a Home button and show the bookmarks bar by using the Chrome extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and no.

`chrome.bookmarks` API doesn't allow you to toggle visibility of the bookmarks bar, and no API exposes home button visibility setting.